# Load product by ID

Tags: product

So I'm quite new to magento.
I know that with `<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>`  you get the currently loaded product and with `$product_id = $this->getProduct()->getId();` you get the ID.
However, I need to load only a specific product by its ID. So for example load the product with the ID 20. 
Would it be something like this:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productID, '20');
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Magento Load Product by ID:**

```
 $productId = 20;
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
```

**Load Product Storewise by ID**

```
 $productId = 20;
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(1)->load($productId);
```

You can display product Name and Sku using these:

```
 echo $product->getSku();
 echo $product->getName();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(20);
```

or if you need the values for a specific store view

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(1)->load(20);
```

Comment: How to apply a filter using the above code for show a different  message to a product page based on product id.  code :  app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml  https://paste.ofcode.org/axc2fhGxRnTiQyVSKwdK2k @Marius